# Qyoto with custom Qt classes and headers

Tags: c#, qt, binding, qyoto

I'm interested to know if there is a way to generate C# bindings for a C++ project that I am working on.  I have found the Qyoto project although I'm pretty sure that is just the Qt headers and doesn't really generate code my own Qt classes and headers.

What I looking for is something like SIP for python but for C#.  Does anyone know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

SIP is a lot like a tool called SWIG (http://www.swig.org). It will automatically creating bindings from C++ to C# (or a bunch of other languages for that matter). It can be a bit of a bear to set up, but it's a powerful tool.

That being said, if you just need to call into the .NET CLR, you might give C++/CLI a try. Here you are able to access any native/unmanaged code and managed .NET code at the same time.

Comment: Swig should work as long as it's run against generated code: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/14441-Wrapping-Qt